# Check wheter there is a relation between two entites hibernate

Tags: hibernate, orm, relational-database, one-to-many

I am using Hibernate as a ORM in my project, where I have two entities in many-to-one relation.

```
@Entity
public class Book {
...
@Id
private int id;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="book")
private List<Page> pages
...
}

@Entity
public class Page {
...
@Id
private int id;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="BOOK_ID")
private Book book;
...
}
```

I have to create a function that gets pair `(bookId,pageId)` and checks whether between those two ids there is a relation. I am curious what way is more 'lightweight' (if there is a difference between presented two approaches) and why.

```
public boolean check(int bookId, int pageId){
    final Book book = entityManager.find(bookId,Book.class);
    final Page page = entityManager.find(pageId, Page.class);
    return page.getBook().getId().equals(book.getId());
}
```

vs

```
public boolean check(int bookId, int pageId){
    final Page page = entityManager.find(pageId, Page.class);
    return page.getBook().getId().equals(bookId);
}
```

Please consider that those listing are simplified and doesn't reflect whole code (and the idea behind it).

Answer (score 0):

The last one approach is more "lightweight" as it required only one direct fetch:

```
entityManager.find(pageId, Page.class);
```

Please also look at [this section](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#fetching-direct-vs-query) of hibernate documentation, as suggested there:

> The Hibernate recommendation is to statically mark all associations lazy and to use dynamic fetching strategies for eagerness.
>
> This is unfortunately at odds with the JPA specification which defines that all one-to-one and many-to-one associations should be eagerly fetched by default.
>
> Hibernate, as a JPA provider, honors that default.

So, I would suggest you to correct your `@ManyToOne` association:

```java
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="BOOK_ID")
private Book book;
```

as for the above case you actually do not need `fetch = FetchType.EAGER`.